# Problem triangle mesh creation with zero angles in the elements (delaunay)

Tags: python, mesh, delaunay

I created a code in Python that help me to create a triangle mesh. However, the mesh file has elements with internal angles of zero and they are not valid for the calculations.

My question is, How can I identify and delete the elements with internal zero angles without deleting the existing nodes in the Delaunay triangulation created?

[csv file structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hbZTX.png)

[exemple mesh problems...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AcJ07.png)

Code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pyvista as pv
import os
from scipy.spatial import Delaunay

path = r"C:\Users\\"
filename = "old_mesh.csv"
datos = np.genfromtxt(path + filename, delimiter=',')

# delete X,Y first line
if np.array_equal(datos[0], np.array([0, 0])):
    datos = np.delete(datos, 0, axis=0)

#verifiy if there are NaN values
if np.isnan(datos).any():
    print("El archivo CSV contiene valores faltantes o NaN")
    # elimina las filas con valores faltantes o NaN
    datos = datos[~np.isnan(datos).any(axis=1)]

# creation of the mesh based in the nodes

tri = Delaunay(datos)

# vtu file creation 
with open(path + os.path.basename(filename)[0:-4] + '_outputmesh.vtu', "w") as f:
    f.write('<?xml version="1.0"?>\n')
    f.write('<VTKFile type="UnstructuredGrid" version="1" byte_order="LittleEndian" header_type="UInt64">\n')
    f.write('\t<UnstructuredGrid>\n')
    f.write('\t\t<Piece NumberOfPoints="{}" NumberOfCells="{}">\n'.format(len(datos), len(tri.simplices)))
    f.write('\t\t\t<Points>\n')
    f.write('\t\t\t\t<DataArray type="Float64" Name="Points" NumberOfComponents="3" format="ascii">\n')
    for i in range(len(datos)):
        f.write('\t\t\t\t\t{} {} {}\n'.format(datos[i][0], datos[i][1], 0))
    f.write('\t\t\t\t</DataArray>\n')
    f.write('\t\t\t</Points>\n')
    f.write('\t\t\t<Cells>\n')
    f.write('\t\t\t\t<DataArray type="Int64" Name="connectivity" NumberOfComponents="1" format="ascii">\n')
    for i in range(len(tri.simplices)):
        f.write('\t\t\t\t\t{} {} {}\n'.format(tri.simplices[i][0], tri.simplices[i][1], tri.simplices[i][2]))
    f.write('\t\t\t\t</DataArray>\n')
    f.write('\t\t\t\t<DataArray type="Int64" Name="offsets" NumberOfComponents="1" format="ascii">\n')
    for i in range(len(tri.simplices)):
        f.write('\t\t\t\t\t{}\n'.format((i+1)*3))
    f.write('\t\t\t\t</DataArray>\n')
    f.write('\t\t\t\t<DataArray type="UInt8" Name="types" NumberOfComponents="1" format="ascii">\n')
    for i in range(len(tri.simplices)):
        f.write('\t\t\t\t\t5\n')
    f.write('\t\t\t\t</DataArray>\n')
    f.write('\t\t\t</Cells>\n')
    f.write('\t\t</Piece>\n')
    f.write('\t</UnstructuredGrid>\n')
    f.write('</VTKFile>')
```

Comment: I didn't bother to read your whole script. But don't loop using `for i in range(len(lst)): lst[i]`, no, this is a bad practice and very inefficient and unPythonic. Whatever tutorial told you this, stop following it immediately, it is bad for you. Use this instead `for i in lst: i`, this iterates over the iterable directly and assigns the current element to `i`. If your iterable is multi-dimensional (for example, each element is a tuple with two values.), use this `for a, b in lst: a, b`

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Please, see the update question and comments, thanks.